# Recaptcha in Rails app regarded as insecure in Chrome and IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am using the recaptcha gem from [here](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha). In chrome the recaptcha box does not appear at all and usually gives no indication that anything was hidden. In internet explorer, the user is prompted with "Only secure content is displayed".

Why is this regarded as insecure? Are there any options I can set in the specified gem to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`recaptcha_tags :ssl => true`](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#to-use-%E2%80%98recaptcha%E2%80%99).